# disabling warning sound for Cisco Anyconnect VPN?

Tags: audio, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

My question is how to disable the warning sounds from Cisco Anyconnect VPN client (4.3.0517 under Windows).

I get a lot of these warning sounds when the client is disconnected from the gateway, attempting to reconnect, or getting re-connected.  This is annoying when the network connection is lossy. (So is the messagebox for these, but to a lesser extent).

I tried to find a place to disable these warnings from its 'Preferences', but couldn't find such an option. I often have to disable the sound of the entire computer when it got noisy.

Is there a way to disable the sound?

Comment: There is a way I'm sure because the AnyConnect my company provides to it's users doesn't make any sound at all. But I don't know how they did it. I'm fairly sure it is either a registry key or a setting in a INI file. There are a lot of options there that you never see in the Preferences of the client.

Comment: When bells ring you could use advanced audio mixer to disable current app (anyconnect) volume.

Comment: Have you tried asking Cisco?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on Windows 10 you can go to

Search > Settings > Windows Settings > Notifications & Actions Settings

and then turn off the sound for the Cisco AnyConnect App under the

Get notifications from these senders section

Ref: https://mstckb.blackbelthelp.com/it/disable-notifications-for-cisco-anyconnect-client/